# How come out the AddressSanitizer error for empty input

Tags: c++

The following code compute the maximum gas between two adjacent elements. The input vector is not sorted.

```
class Solution {
public:
int maximumGap(vector<int>& nums) {
    int max = 0;
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size() -1; i++) {
        if(nums[i+1] > nums[i] + max) max = nums[i+1] - nums[i];
    }
    return max;
}
};
```

However, it generates the following error if input is empty (e.g. [])

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000004 (pc     0x00000040d54a bp 0x7ffe00e1e520 sp 0x7ffe00e1df50 T0)
==29==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==29==Hint: address points to the zero page.
#1 0x7fde1d3ab2e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==29==ABORTING
```

The problem can be solved by including the following:

```
if(nums.empty()) return 0;
```

Just wondering how does the error come about? I thought an empty input should also output 0 for the original code.

Comment: Try `std::cout << (nums.size() -1);`

Comment: The code looks correct so far, so it must be something else that you are not showing. Maybe the function call?

Answer (score 1):

`nums.size()` is of an unsigned type, so when it is zero, `nums.size() - 1` is a huge positive number, and your loop will run.

You can fix that by rewriting your loop condition as:

```cpp
i + 1 < nums.size()
```